# Is it possible to do Seed per Migration in Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to seed database for each migration while doing `update-database`. Is there anyway i can get it done. Does Entity Framework support it already or do i need to go with custom code.

I have no idea where to start. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Seed() method on your context](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) that runs only when the database is created. Use this for basic data like test users and system config you need to minimally run your app.

There is also Migration Seed() which runs every time you do `update-database` regardless of whether there is a pending migration. Use idempotent commands like [AddOrUpdate](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/) so data doesn't get added multiple times.

If you are adding a new table in a migration you can populate it by adding custome Sql commands Sql("INSERT ...") within that migration.